# getUsers function get in the browser but doenst appear

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im making a get Users function(React/Laravel) from a backend i made before(and its working, i use the same backend in a Vue project).

```
getUsers = async () => {
    await axios

        .get(url + "api/alunos")
        .then((response) => {
            this.state.alunos = response.data;
            console.log(response.data)
            console.log(this.state.alunos)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.warn(error);
        });
};


componentDidMount() {
    this.getUsers();
}
```

In the console.log(response.data) and console.log(this.state.alunos) i get the array(1)  data: Array(1)
0: {id: 1, nome: "Mary"...}

but doesnt appear in the browser, i get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

the error is in the "this.props.alunos.map":

```
          {this.props.alunos.map(aluno =>
                <tr key={aluno.id}>
                    <td>{aluno.id}</td>
                    <td>{aluno.nome}</td>
                </tr>
            )}
```

Variables:

```
state = {
    alunos: [],
    aluno: {
        nome: '',
    },
    data: [],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you assign it to **`alunos`** in the `setState` call, you have to access it using **`this.state.alunos`**. Also you need to use just `aluno` everywhere inside `map()` because that is your input variable.

The result:

```
{this.state.alunos.map(aluno => {
    return (
        <tr key={aluno.id}>
            <td>{aluno.id}</td>
            <td>{aluno.nome}</td>
        </tr>
    )
})}
```

This can further be simplified by leaving out the `{ }` braces and the `return`:

```
{this.state.alunos.map(aluno =>
    <tr key={aluno.id}>
        <td>{aluno.id}</td>
        <td>{aluno.nome}</td>
    </tr>
)}
```

---

The above is true if (and only if) all the code is in **one component**.

If you have a child component that does the `.map()`, and a parent that does the `getUsers()` call, then you need to pass the `this.state.alunos` array from the parent to the child as a property:

```
<Child alunos={this.state.alunos} />
```

And then use `this.props.alunos.map(....)` in the child, because it is now a parameter that is coming from the outside.

Comment: when i change "data" from "this.state.data.map..." i get an error TypeError: this.state.alunos.map is not a function. I did both cases and it didnt work :/

Comment: I update the answer, please see if that applies.

Comment: i changed in the parent getUsers() to "this.state.alunos = response.data;" when i use console.log(this.state.alunos) the array is there. In the child when i change to {this.props.alunos.map...} i get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". I will edit the post with the changes

Comment: I did it !!!! i used "this.setState({ alunos: response.data.data });" in the getUsers and " {this.state.alunos.map((aluno)"!!! Peter, thank you so much!!!

Comment: Ah, a `data` property *inside* the axios `response.data` object... missed that, glad you found it

Answer (score 1):

You should access the data from `aluno` Object when accessing inside HTML/JSX Element.

```
{this.state.servicios.map(aluno => {
  return (
    <tr key={aluno.id}>
        <td>{aluno.id}</td>
        <td>{aluno.nome}</td>
    </tr>
  )
})}
```

Comment: I tried that, but when i change "data" i get the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined